# How to implement a bytecode scripting language with local labels and symbol linking in C, without using assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, scripting, linker, bytecode

I'm trying to create a bytecode scripting language in C. The language in stored in a bytecode format and consists of a command byte or opcode optionally followed by a number of parameters, with include things like constants, but also pointers.

```
cmd arg0, arg1 -> 0xfe 0xa0 0xa1
cmd2 symbol    -> 0xde <symbol's address>
```

I wanted to implement the scripting language in C, but I'm having trouble doing so.

Trying to place pointers into a `uint8_t` results in compile errors.

```c
#define cmd2(_s) 0xde, (uint8_t)((uintptr_t)_s & 0xff), ...
// OR
#define cmd2(_s) 0xde, ((uint8_t*)&_s)[0], ...
const uint8_t my_script[] = {
  cmd2(symbol)
};
```

Using unions makes each command take up too much space.

```c
struct Cmd {
  uint8_t op;
  union {
    struct Cmd2 {
      void* ptr; // Now each cmd is at least 8 or 16 bytes w/ padding.
    } cmd2;
  };
};

#define op_cmd2(_s) {.op = 0xde, .cmd2={_s}}
const struct Cmd my_script[] = {
  op_cmd2(symbol),
};
```

Trying to write the scripts outside of C (like with a python script or something) means I can't put C symbols into the code and have it work. The frustrating part is, I know how to do these things in assembly. With some macros, I can have the assembler generate the bytecode like I want.

```
macro cmd2
  .byte 0xde
  .addr \1
endm

MyScript::
  cmd2 symbol
```

The problem is, I don't WANT to use assembly. I want to use C for its portability. Is there something else I haven't tried that could work?

Comment: If you're really asking about how to design the structure of your bytecode, then casting the problem in terms of how to express an instance of the bytecode via an array initializer seems a big miss.  Maybe you can't easily do that, but so what?  An array initializer is by no means the only way, or even a particularly interesting way, to obtain bytecode to feed to your interpreter.

Comment: I don't understand your troubles. If you already have the bytecode ISA (particularly, how each instruction should be encoded) you just have to deal with strings of bytes, which is pretty natural in C. The exact code and macro to use depend heavily on the API you want to create. You can have an abstract representation of an instruction and a pair of encode and decode methods or you can have a [macro for each instruction](https://godbolt.org/z/67YednzKh) (you don't need macro foo expertise since you have to pickup the endianness and size for the instruction immediates).

Comment: The problem is, I want to have C symbols automatically linkable inside the bytecode. In your example, if I define a function foo and pass it into cmd2, the compiler will complain about the fact that foo is not a constant expression. The thing is, I want to tell the compiler, "Hey, just put a relocation thing here so that the linker can put foo here at link time." As far as I know, the only way to do that in C is to use the union trick, which as I said earlier, wastes lots of space.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to statically define an array that is your script then I think you will have to use constant-length command representations and waste some memory but gain speed. If you are ok with commands that need to be initialized dynamically, you could use flexible arrays:

```c
struct Cmd {
    uint8_t op;
    uint8_t params[];
}
```

The array size can be different for each instance. Someplace else you will need to store a static mapping of opcodes to number of params (assuming this is a static mapping in your language):

```c
int op_nparams[256] = {
    [0] = 0, // opcode 0 has no additional params.
    [1] = 2, // opcode 1 takes two params.
    // And so on...
};
```

You will use this mapping to know how much space to allocate for each command, and how much to step ahead in an array of commands to reach the next member.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pointer table and use byte indexes in the script. If some pointer is used more than once, this even saves space. In worst case (pointer is used only once) the overhead will be one byte on that specific command and pointer, but you save space anyway on all other commands without pointers. If you want, you can build a pointer table of structures `{ &v, sizeof(v) },` and implement universal commands like clr(value) to fill all variable bytes with zero, etc. If you are sure about maximum size, you can use `uint8_t` for the size field.

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint8_t array1[];
extern uint32_t value1;
extern uint16_t value2;

// Add here all variables to save pointers to
#define PTR_LIST \
    ADDPTR(array1), \
    ADDPTR(value2), \
    ADDPTR(value1)

// Generate indexes
#define ADDPTR(v) v ## _entry
enum ptr_indexes {
    PTR_LIST,
    PTR_INDEX_MAX
};
#undef ADDPTR

#if PTR_INDEX_MAX > 256
#error "Pointer table overflow"
#endif

// Store pointers in array
#define ADDPTR(v) &v
const void *ptr_array[] = {
    PTR_LIST
};
#undef ADDPTR

#define cmd0      0x01,
#define cmd1(a,b) 0xfe, a, b,
#define cmd2(v) 0xde, v ## _entry,

const uint8_t script[] = {
    cmd1(0xa0,0xa1)
    cmd2(array1)
    cmd0
    cmd2(value1)
    cmd2(value2)
};
```

UPD:
Indeed, you can use more than 256 pointers because enum value is a constant and you  can use math in cmd macros

```
#define cmd2(ptr) 0xde, ptr ## _entry & 0xFF, ptr ## _entry >> 8,
```

Anyway, I think it is not necessary